# How do I post multiple parameters to a URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, parameters

I need to post to this URL

https://liceoeuroamericano.territorio.la/webservices/persona.php

---

I need to post 2 different Parameters

1. method
2. param

   ```
      method=activateUser

      param 
      {    
           "auth_key": "123456",
           "user": "[email]",
           "active":"[0/1]"
      }
      string(JSON)
   ```

---

### What I have Tried - AM I doing anything right?

```
<button id="activateUser">GO</button>
<script>
$('#activateUser').on('click', function(){


  $.post('https://liceoeuroamericano.territorio.la/webservices/persona.php',    

   {
    method=activateUser&params={    
    "auth_key": "123456",
    "user": "[email]",
    "active":"[0/1]"
   }
   string(JSON)
   }, function(data){

   })   

});

</script>
```

Comment: `{method=...}`? that's not even close to being valid javascript.

Comment: Check your console, it *will* help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your requirements you need to pass `method` as a string, then JSON encode the `params` object. If so, this should work for you:

```js
$.post('https://liceoeuroamericano.territorio.la/webservices/persona.php', {
    method: 'activateUser',
    params: JSON.stringify({    
        auth_key: "123456",
        user: "[email]",
        active: "[0/1]"
    })
}, function(data){
    console.log('request completed successfully');
})
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, method is a parameter